# The "AdjustJavacVersionArguments" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have started developing `Xamarin.Forms` applications in `Visual Studio Enterprise 2015` as a beginner. When I build my solution I am getting an error like this:

> The "AdjustJavacVersionArguments" task failed unexpectedly.
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The "AdjustJavacVersionArguments" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AdjustJavacVersionArguments.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() XamarinDemo.Android

What exactly this error means? Do I have a problem with my JDK version?

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Have you found any fix?

Comment: The answer given below didn't solve your problem? @OlorunfemiAjibulu

Comment: No. It didn't. I actually installed JDK 10 alongside 8 which I uninstalled and re-installed 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was solved. I uninstalled JDK v9 and instead installed JDK v8. Later on, in Visual Studio I selected "Tools" -> "Options" and just scrolled down a little and found "Xamarin" -> "Android Settings" and changed the `Java Development Kit Location` with the path where the JDK v8 is located. After building the solution, error has been gone.