# Xamarin.Android Dev with Rider - Change JDK Version back to 1.8

Tags: java-8, xamarin.android, rider

We are currently developing a Xamarin.Forms Application under Mac OS with Jetbrains Rider. We are running into this error [The "AdjustJavacVersionArguments" task failed unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934715/the-adjustjavacversionarguments-task-failed-unexpectedly) when we try to run the Xamarin.Droid App in the Emulator. To solve this issue we want to set the JDK back to Version 1.8 (right now it is 1.9, which seems not to work at all).

Where can we do this in Rider? We havn't found any option for this in the global-, or project- specific settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Tuning_the_IDE.html).

> JetBrains Rider includes JetBrains Runtime (based on OpenJDK 8), which is used by default.

1) On the Help menu, click Find Action, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

2) Find and select the Switch IDE boot JDK action.

3) Select the desired JDK and click OK.

Comment: You are my hero. Changing the Version from JetBrains JDK 8 to System wide JDK 8 solved the problem!